# Showing a list of records which contains similar values in one column

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a table named 'Tbluser'. It contains 'company_code, user_code'.I can show this table using grid view. 
i want to show only one specific company users. example, if a company_code: 'company1' logs in, he can only see user_code and company_code associated with company1.

How can i select only those attributes with 'company1'? Is there any function which provides all the attributes for a single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this via the data provider for example

```
public function myDataProvider()
{
   $id = Yii::app()->user->name;
   $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('MODELNAME', array(
                'criteria'=>array(
                'condition'=>'company_code= :id',
                'params' => array(':id' => $id),
                 ), 
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>5,
            ),
    ));
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

I presume that company1 is the users name. If not simply change it to say username/id etc.

Many thanks to Veelen for suggested edit (using params protects against sql injections).

Comment: It's veelen actually :)

Comment: @veelen, Whoops, my apologies, cheers for the heads up on params.